# Sign up Firebase expo problem react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

I am trying to create a Sign up/Sign in system with firebase, my code is as follows:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Platform } from "react-native";
import { FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal } from "expo-firebase-recaptcha";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import { useRef } from 'react';
 
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";
 
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, PhoneAuthProvider, verifyPhoneNumber } from "firebase/auth";
 
 
 
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "XXXXX-1bd3c.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://XXXXX-1bd3c-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
    projectId: "XXX-1bd3c",
    storageBucket: "XXXX-1bd3c.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "216430XXXX6",
    appId: "1:216430389096:web:ea8a9d68cf1caf8XXXXX",
    measurementId: "G-SN2Q56XXXX"
};
 
getApps().length === 0 ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();
 
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 
 
const auth = getAuth();
 
//const firebase = require('firebase');
 
 
// Initialize Firebase JS SDK
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
 
export default function App() {
 
  //const defaultAuth = firebase.auth();
 
 
 
  const recaptchaVerifier = useRef(null);
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState();
  const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = useState();
  const [verificationCode, setVerificationCode] = useState();
 // const firebaseConfig = firebase.apps.length ? firebase.app().options : undefined;
  const [message, showMessage] = useState((!firebaseConfig || Platform.OS === 'web')
    ? { text: "To get started, provide a valid firebase config in App.js and open this snack on an iOS or Android device."}
    : undefined);
 
  return (
    <View style={{ padding: 20, marginTop: 50 }}>
      <FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
        ref={recaptchaVerifier}
        firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}
      />
      <Text style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>Enter phone number</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{ marginVertical: 10, fontSize: 17 }}
        placeholder="+1 999 999 9999"
        autoFocus
        autoCompleteType="tel"
        keyboardType="phone-pad"
        textContentType="telephoneNumber"
        onChangeText={(phoneNumber) => setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)}
      />
      <Button
        title="Send Verification Code"
        disabled={!phoneNumber}
        onPress={async () => {
          // The FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal ref implements the
          // FirebaseAuthApplicationVerifier interface and can be
          // passed directly to `verifyPhoneNumber`.
          try {
            const phoneProvider = PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID; 
            const verificationId = await phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
              phoneNumber,
              recaptchaVerifier.current
            );
            setVerificationId(verificationId);
            showMessage({
              text: "Verification code has been sent to your phone.",
            });
          } catch (err) {
            showMessage({ text: `Error: ${err.message}`, color: "red" });
            console.log(err.message);
          }
        }}
      />
      <Text style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>Enter Verification code</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{ marginVertical: 10, fontSize: 17 }}
        editable={!!verificationId}
        placeholder="123456"
        onChangeText={setVerificationCode}
      />
      <Button
        title="Confirm Verification Code"
        disabled={!verificationId}
        onPress={async () => {
          try {
            const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
              verificationId,
              verificationCode
            );
            await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
            showMessage({ text: "Phone authentication successful " });
          } catch (err) {
            showMessage({ text: `Error: ${err.message}`, color: "red" });
          }
        }}
      />
      {message ? (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, { backgroundColor: 0xffffffee, justifyContent: "center" }]}
          onPress={() => showMessage(undefined)}>
          <Text style={{color: message.color || "blue", fontSize: 17, textAlign: "center", margin: 20, }}>
            {message.text}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ) : undefined}
    </View>
  );
}
```

The error I get is: phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber is not a function. (In 'phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, recaptchaVerifier.current)', 'phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber' is undefined)

I searched everywhere on Google, but couldn't find any solutions. I was inspired by this link: https://snack.expo.dev/@sid/firebase-phone-auth

Comment: Try changing `PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID()` to `PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID`. No `()`. It's a static property on that class and not a method. From the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider#static-provider_id

Comment: Hi I did this and now I have : phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber is not a function. (In 'phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, recaptchaVerifier.current)', 'phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber' is undefined). So thanks it resolved the initial error.